# What's the equivalent of mouseenter and mouseleave event in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to develop an app in React-Native, and I need to know that while you're swiping your finger in the screen and if you are on top of a component then to change color (basically just like we do with buttons on hover). `onPress` method does not work, since you may press out of it in the beginning then while you're swiping you might be on top of that (button), and only then I need to change the color of it.

So I need something like `mouseeneter` and `mouseleave` events on the web.

I also tried to add `onStartShouldSetResponder`, `onMoveShouldSetResponder`, `onResponderMove`, `onResponderRelease` referencing to: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system , but that doesn't seem to work. That's because in style I'm working with `position: absolute` and its not working properly.

Comment: maybe you can check [gesture handler](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/about-handlers.html)

Comment: did anyone found the solution?